# Merging multiple tex files into one standalone tex file

Tags: tools

Suppose I have two `tex` files, `document.tex` and `content.tex`

`document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is some content.

\input{content.tex}

\end{document}
```

`content.tex`:

```
This is some more content.
```

Compiling with `pdflatex document.tex` produces the expected document as pdf. However, I'd like to create a new standalone `tex` file, that would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is some content.

This is some more content.

\end{document}
```

I'm almost sure there must be a standard tool to do this, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: I'd say the standard tool is a text editor equipped with copy/paste. You might want to explain *why* you are trying to do this from within TeX.

Comment: Sure, that would work. But it's tedious and error prone if you have documents with dozens of externals. As to _why_, I needed to do this for a submission some time ago and did it manually then. And given that there's a bunch of little known (at least to me) command line tools for all kinds of jobs I thought chances are there is one for this task, too.

Comment: Yes, `latexpand` does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!